# Get commits that have been *created* on a specific branch

Tags: git

Is there a (relatively simple) way to *only* get the commits corresponding to asterisks (*) on the `release` (left-most, marked by red frame) branch in this real-world example of a commit history?

[image]

The given set of commits are all high-risk commits (i.e. commits that are exposed to the public). There can only be two kinds of commits on the `release` (and/or `master`) branch(es):

1. Actual releases (usually tagged, big merges)
2. Hotfixes (usually un-tagged, small merges)

My goal: I want to create statistics and small analytical tools that use these commits to help us (and especially our developers) to better understand high-risk code regions and possible bug patterns. I am also convinced that this can eventually be used to help us better estimate risk for the company and evaluate QA efficiency.

Any suggestions?

PS: This graph has been created with `git log --oneline --decorate --graph`, but I cut all sensitive information from it.

Comment: You write: *[...] only get the commits [...]*. Do you mean "get a log" of the corresponding revisions? This might work: `git log --first-parent release`.

Comment: @Jubobs `first-parent` is awesome! From what I understand it should work in our current working environment, but maybe I am overlooking something. Are there any scary scenarios where this would stop working (given we keep treating our git sanely, don't rename branches etc.)? To answer your question: Any way of obtaining all the commit hashes is fine! :)

Comment: Well, under the assumption that you and your collaborators only ever merge some other branch *into* `release` (as opposed to merging `release` into some other branch), `--first-parent` should do what you want. You can use `git rev-list --first-parent` if you only want a list of the commit hashes (`rev-list` is the plumbing analogue to `log`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Under the assumption that you and your collaborators only ever merge some other branch *into* `release`** (as opposed to merging `release` into some other branch), then

```
git log --first-parent release
```

should give you a log of the commits of interest, because

> The first parent is the branch you were on when you merged [...]

([Pro Git Book, 7.1](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#Ancestry-References))

If you're only interested in the commit hashes, you can run

```
git log --first-parent --pretty="%H" release
```

instead. However, in a programmatic setting (script, etc.), you should prefer `rev-list` (plumbing) over `log` (porcelain):

```
git rev-list --first-parent
```

Comment: I saw "rev-list" vs. "porcelain" before. What does it mean?

Comment: Also, we of course first merge `release`  into feature and hotfix branches, which then ultimately get merged back. Under what circumstances will that break things, because so far `--first-parent` seems to work as expected, on this repository.

Comment: @Domi `--first-parent` tells `log` (or `rev-list`) to only follow the first parent upon seeing a merge commit. Whether that's what you want or not is unclear; I'm not sure which are the commits that you enclosed in red. You should probably experiment with that flag and see if you get the desired list of commits.